# How to define a php constant with parameter to prevent a sonar alert

Tags: php

I am using laravel 8 and sonarcloud.

I have some controllers with some "code smells" about duplication code. This code , for example, is duplicated 3 times in the same controller :

```
return redirect('/organizations/' . $organization->id . '/classified-ads')
```

Sonar cloud suggests to define a constant. So I would like to do something like that :

```
CONST REDIRECT = 'a string with a parameter'
```

and then :

```
return redirect(self::REDIRECT)
```

But how to write this constant, as it contains the parameter **$organization->id**  ?

Comment: You can not define a constant with parameter, as you knew constants are like variables but their value can not be changed once defined/initialized. You could use a `function` to get the `organization id` and frame the  URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```
private static function getClassifyAdsURL($organizationId) {
  return '/organizations/' . $organizationId . '/classified-ads';
}

...

In your Controller `return` statement:
return self::getClassifyAdsURL($organization->id);

...
```